# How to create Angular gradient in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, gradient, figma

[image]

I want to create an angular gradient like this in Android Jetpack Compose.

[image]

The gradient is made in Figma and below is the android code in Figma Inspect.

[image]

I could only find resources for the linear gradient with only [one angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68218714/angled-gradient-background-in-jetpack-compose/71577924#71577924).

How can I create this Angular gradient in Jetpack compose?

Answer (score 5):

What you need is `Brush.sweepGradient` with colorStops and setting center correctly. Gradient stops start from 3'o clock, right center, so you need to add 0.25 to each stop and move the ones that pass 1 to start, i moved 2 colors from bottom to top at 0.01, and 0.14

```
@Composable
private fun SweepGradientExample() {
    val colorStops = listOf(
        0.01f to Color(0x8C1339FF),
        0.14f to Color(0x8CFF13A1),
        0.31f to Color(0x8C1380FF),
        0.54f to Color(0x8CD013FF),
        0.81f to Color(0x8C7B13FF),
    ).toTypedArray()

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val centerX: Float
    val centerY: Float
    with(density) {
        centerX = 161.dp.toPx() / 2
        centerY = 97.dp.toPx() / 2
    }
    val brush = Brush.sweepGradient(
        colorStops = colorStops,
        center = Offset(centerX, centerY)
    )
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(width = 161.dp, height = 97.dp)
        .background(brush)
    )
}
```

Result

[image]