# Gradient Line color in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I want to draw gradient line in jetpack compose. I tried some code but it was not correct as my expected.

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DrawTimeLine() {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        repeat(2) { index ->
            val (height, brush) = if (index == 0) {
                75.dp to Brush.linearGradient(listOf(Color.Blue, Color.Red))
            } else {
                25.dp to Brush.linearGradient(listOf(Color.Red, Color.Red))
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(height)
                    .drawBehind {
                        drawLine(
                            brush = brush,
                            start = Offset(x = center.x, y = 0F),
                            end = Offset(x = center.x, y = size.height),
                            strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx(),
                        )
                    }
            ) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Brush.linearGradient` creates a gradient with **45** degrees angle by default using start and end values. It's possible to change rotation angle , changing by 45 degrees is quite simple, rotating by other degrees require extending Brush i think, you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71716708/5457853) for gradient angle rotation.

You can either change it by 90 degrees by setting start and end appropriately or use `Brush.verticalGradient` which more is more convenient way to do it.

```
@Stable
fun verticalGradient(
    vararg colorStops: Pair<Float, Color>,
    startY: Float = 0f,
    endY: Float = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    tileMode: TileMode = TileMode.Clamp
): Brush = Brush.linearGradient(
    *colorStops,
    start = Offset(0.0f, startY),
    end = Offset(0.0f, endY),
    tileMode = tileMode
)
```

If you draw a line at any point using linear brush will see that you are drawing segments of rectangle gradient below because gradient is set based on start and end positions.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun GradientTest() {
    val brush = Brush.linearGradient(listOf(Color.Blue, Color.Red))

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
    ) {

        var positionX by remember {
            mutableStateOf(0f)
        }

        Slider(
            value = positionX,
            onValueChange = {
                positionX = it
            },
            valueRange = 0f..1000f
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .drawBehind {
                    drawRect(
                        brush = brush
                    )
                }

        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(.5f)
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .drawBehind {
                    drawLine(
                        brush = brush,
                        start = Offset(positionX, 0f),
                        end = Offset(positionX, size.height),
                        strokeWidth = 40f
                    )
                }
        )
    }
}
```

AS J.K answered using `Brush.verticalGradient` which equally proportions the color between the height of the composable. If you use color stops you can define which color should take which percentage

```
val verticalBrush = Brush.verticalGradient(
    listOf(Color.Blue, Color.Red)
)

val verticalBrush2 = Brush.verticalGradient(
    0.25f to Color.Blue,
    1f to Color.Red,
)
```

[image]

Comment: Simply Awesome.

Comment: After updating to compose version 1.5.3, vertival gradient is only displaying black line. Providing single color works fine though

Answer (score 3):

```
Brush.verticalGradient(listOf(Color.Red, Color.Red))
```

Please try this.

Comment: how do you understand that is `verticalGradient` ?

Comment: I have tried the variants of brushes for curiosity :)