# How to use list value in vararg in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have pairs value and want to use in `vararg`. The value is something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76235677/8266651)

```
val verticalBrush2 = Brush.verticalGradient(
    0.25f to Color.Blue,
    1f to Color.Red,
)
```

I have some business logic to use different colors. So I converted into like this

```
val brushColors = listOf(0.25f to Color.Blue, 1f to Color.Red)
```

Now I passed in `drawLine` brush [parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Brush#verticalGradient(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.TileMode)) which is type of `vararg`. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65520425) to convert into `toTypedArray()`.

```
                    drawLine(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                            listOf(0.25f to Color.Blue, 1f to Color.Red)
                                .map { it }
                                .toTypedArray()
                        ),
                        start = Offset(x = 0F, y = 0F),
                        end = Offset(x = 0F, y = size.height),
                        strokeWidth = 3.dp.toPx(),
                    )
```

But still gives me error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the spread operator. From [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> When you call a vararg-function, you can pass arguments individually, for example asList(1, 2, 3). If you already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, use the spread operator (prefix the array with *):

So you have to convert your list to array **and** use the spread operator:

```
Brush.verticalGradient(*brushColors.toTypedArray())
```

You don't need `.map { it }`, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Another question I tried without using spread operator and it works i.e. `Brush.verticalGradient(brushColors.toTypedArray())`

Comment: so what is the difference between both?

Comment: That's weird. There are two overloads of `verticalGradient`, one takes `colors: List<Color>`, the other `vararg colorStops: Pair<Float, Color>`. So if you don't need to specify the color stops, you can use the one with list.

Comment: yeah it sounds confusing..

Comment: But if you already have array of `Pair<Float, Color>`, it doesn't work for me without the spread operator...

Comment: hmm strange. I'll try to clean and build and run